# What do you call the stuff that animals use to mark their territory?

Tags: phrase-usage

For instance, lions use their urine to mark their territory.

What's the common way to refers to these "marks"? Territorial marks? (Not sure if this is common usage, though, since Google Books only returns [328](https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=%22territorial%20mark%22&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0CA4Q_AUoAGoVChMIs5SUz5S_xwIVgiKmCh1pMwZB&biw=1280&bih=938) results.)

Comment: *Piss* is a bit vulgar, and not very technical. I'd say "urine" if I were you.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Sorry, I wasn't being too scientific. Fixed.

Comment: "Scent".  The scent may be in urine, feces, or in other substances emitted by special glands.  (You have scent glands under your arms and in your groin area.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is called ***[scent marking](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Territory_(animal)#Scent_marking)*** (also known as ***territorial marking or spraying)***:

> - ***Scent marking***, also known as territorial marking or spraying when this involves urination, is a behaviour used by animals to identify their territory.
> - ***Most commonly, this is accomplished by depositing strong-smelling substances contained in the urine, faeces, or, from specialised scent glands located on various areas of the body.*** Often, the scent contains pheromones or carrier proteins such as the major urinary proteins to stabilize the odours and maintain them for longer. The animal sniffing the scent mark will frequently display a flehmen response to assist in communication of the information.
> - ***Not only does scent marking communicate information to conspecifics, but can also indicate the presence of the territory-holder to prey species.*** For example, felids such as leopards and jaguars mark by rubbing themselves against vegetation.

Wikipedia

Comment: +1 for *spraying* which is the term I'm most familiar with, but easy to miss among all the words in bold type. [Urine spraying in cats](http://icatcare.org/advice/problem-behaviour/urine-spraying-cats)